# how to not count 0 when doing row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am doing a `row_number()` over some data.

My problem is that I do not wnat to take into account data that is `0`.

Here's my data sample:

```
+-----------+-----+
| Alex      |   1 |
| Liza      |   2 |
| Harry     |   0 |
| Marge     |  24 |
| Bla       |   0 |
| Something | 234 |
+-----------+-----+
```

Here's what I want:

```
+-----------+--------+------------+
|   name    | number | row_number |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| Harry     |      0 |          0 |
| Bla       |      0 |          0 |
| Something |    234 |          1 |
| Marge     |     24 |          2 |
| Liza      |      2 |          3 |
| Alex      |      1 |          4 |
+-----------+--------+------------+
```

as you can see the third column is `the row_number()`

this is what I have so far:

```
select name, number, row_number() over (partition by name order by name,number)
from myTable
```

How do I get the query above to return `0` for all `0's` in the source data and **not count the 0's at all towards the row_number sequence**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1b5b/5):

```
SELECT name, number, 0 as [row_number]
FROM myTable
WHERE number = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT name, number, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY number DESC)
FROM myTable
WHERE number <> 0
```

Comment: thank you very much i will try it right now. just to confirm with you, the row_number will not take into account values where number=0?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select name, number,
       (case when number = 0 then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by iszero order by number desc)
        end) as row_number
from (select t.*, (case when number = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as iszero
      from myTable t
     ) t
```

Since you are ordering by numbers descending, the following works if no numbers are negative:

```
select name, number,
       (case when number = 0 then 0
             else row_number() over (order by number desc)
        end) as row_number
from myTable t
```